# How to deal with NaN in R?

Tags: r

I have two binary files with the same dimensions(corr and rmse ).I want to do this:
replace all pixels in rmse by NA whenevr corr is NA.

file1:

```
conne <- file("D:\\omplete.bin","rb")
corr<- readBin(conne, numeric(), size=4,  n=1440*720, signed=TRUE)
```

file2:

```
rms <- file("D:\\hgmplete.bin","rb")
rmse<- readBin(rms, numeric(), size=4,  n=1440*720, signed=TRUE)
```

I did this:

```
rmse[corr==NA]=NA
```

did not do anything, so I tried this:

```
rmse[corr==NaN]=NA
```

did not do anything either! Can anybody help me on this.

Head of the file corr:

```
> corr
[1] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Comment: check for `?is.na` (gives true for both NA and NaN).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the logical test `is.nan()`. In this case:

```
rmse[is.nan(corr)]=NA
```

should do the trick